# How to update all permalinks in site

Tags: permalinks

So my client has changed all the titles of pages and posts... but the permalinks have not changed from the original title.

I have tried changing the permalink configuration, but when I go back to the `Post Name` option the permalinks haven't changed.

Is there a way to update all permalinks without messing with the database?

Comment: Are none of the permalink options doing anything?

Comment: @BandonRandon Sorry, I didn't try all the options. Some change, but the one I want (postname) reamins the same.

Comment: Have you tried to reset all permalinks to default structure and then update for your new permalinks?

Comment: @JMa I changed to default and then to postname again. Is that what you mean? Is there another way to reset permalinks?

Comment: Yeah I meant that